# Magento 1.9 out of memory

Tags: php, apache, magento, magento-1.9

I have a project installed by git, composer dependencies are updated, database installed (/app/etc/config.xml). Running xampp with php 7.1 (4GB memory limit).

PHP throws the same error every time, memory limit doesn't affect this.

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried
>   to allocate 262144 bytes) in
>   Z:\www\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource.php on line 209

'tried to allocate bytes' doen't change with php memory limit. How to troubleshoot that problem?

Z:\www\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource.php

```
/**
 * Retrieve default connection name by required connection name
 *
 * @param string $requiredConnectionName
 * @return string
 */
protected function _getDefaultConnection($requiredConnectionName)
{
    if (strpos($requiredConnectionName, 'read') !== false) {
        return $this->getConnection(self::DEFAULT_READ_RESOURCE);
    }
    return $this->getConnection(self::DEFAULT_WRITE_RESOURCE); // <-- line 209
}
```

Comment: Do you have any values set in `app/etc/local.xml` that might be overriding `config.xml`? It sounds like it's stuck in a loop - looking at the code, `getConnection()` calls `_getDefaultConnection()` again if it doesn't get a value back from `Mage::getConfig()->getResourceConnectionConfig($name)`

Comment: @benJ no, I have only `local.xml.temlate` and `local.xml.additional`. And as their comments say, those are not overriding anything, only `local.xml`.